# Declaring variable workbook / Worksheet vba

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I know this might come off as a trivial question, but I can't seem to declare a `workbook` or a `worksheet` as a variable in `VBA`. I have the following code, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, it should be straight forward. Normally I don't have any problems declaring variables such as `Dim i As Integer` etc.

```
sub kl() 

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheet("name")

    wb.ws.Select

End Sub
```

When I run the above code, I receive a `type missmatch` error.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Is this VBA for excel?

Comment: See this: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/

Comment: In addition to the `Sheets` issue, your ws variable is a variable, not a property of a workbook, so it's just `ws.select` not `wb.ws.select`. Also note that you very rarely need to select anything in VBA.

Comment: the error i recieve is "type missmatch"

Answer (score 24):

Use **Sheets** rather than **Sheet** and activate them sequentially:

```
Sub kl()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    wb.Activate
    ws.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This is correct. However the `wb.activate` is probably superfluous. If `wb` is assigned to the `activeworkbook` two lines above, then it is already activated.

Comment: @JNevill  **good point**  I used two statements in case the user wanted to modify the **Set** to point to some other workbook.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help, if i do the above, i still get the error "type missmatch". so this doesn't work either, i have experimented with all sorts of combinations of sheet and sheets, but nothing works. Really frustrating because i have this large script that i will have to change several times, and would be nice to only change the sheet name in the top variable.

Comment: Note that the `Sheets` collection contains `Worksheet` objects, but also `Chart`, and a bunch of legacy sheet types too. Use the `Worksheets` collection if you want to retrieve an actual `Worksheet` object.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Good point!  We can usually rely on the Name.  Specifying `Sheets("Sheet1")` has a REALLY good chance of  being a worksheet.  Something like `Sheets(1)` might be a Chart,etc. *(but you suggestion is better)*

Comment: *Usually* - but `Name` also has a non-zero chance of being modified by the user, thereby breaking any & all VBA code that's hard-coding it ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug  Amen to that!...............I hate when users change worksheet names............I neverr feel comfortable using code names...........

Comment: I've put up an answer =)  you can prevent users messing up sheet names/indices by protecting workbook structure =)

Answer (score 16):

If the worksheet you want to retrieve exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. the workbook that contains the VBA code you're looking at), then the simplest and most consistently reliable way to refer to that `Worksheet` object is to use its *code name*:

```
Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
```

You can set the *code name* to anything you need (as long as it's a valid VBA identifier), independently of its "tab name" (which the user can modify at any time), by changing the `(Name)` property in the *Properties* toolwindow (F4):

[image: Sheet1 properties]

The `Name` property refers to the "tab name" that the user can change on a whim; the `(Name)` property refers to the *code name* of the worksheet, and the user can't change it without accessing the Visual Basic Editor.

VBA uses this *code name* to automatically declare a global-scope `Worksheet` object variable that your code gets to use anywhere to refer to that sheet, for free.

In other words, if the sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, there's never a need to declare a variable for it - the variable is already there!

---

If the worksheet is created at run-time (inside `ThisWorkbook` or not), *then* you need to declare & assign a `Worksheet` variable for it.

Use the `Worksheets` property of a `Workbook` object to retrieve it:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(path)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(nameOrIndex)
```

---

#### Important notes...

- Both the name and index of a worksheet can easily be modified by the user (accidentally or not), **unless workbook structure is protected**. If workbook isn't protected, you simply cannot assume that the name or index alone will give you the specific worksheet you're after - it's always a good idea to validate the format of the sheet (e.g. verify that cell A1 contains some specific text, or that there's a table with a specific name, that contains some specific column headings).
- Using the `Sheets` collection contains `Worksheet` objects, but can also contain `Chart` instances, and a half-dozen more legacy sheet types that are **not worksheets**. Assigning a `Worksheet` reference from whatever `Sheets(nameOrIndex)` returns, risks throwing a *type mismatch* run-time error for that reason.
- Not *qualifying* the `Worksheets` collection is an *implicit ActiveWorkbook reference* - meaning the `Worksheets` collection is pulling from whatever workbook is active at the moment the instruction is executing. Such implicit references make the code frail and bug-prone, especially if the user can navigate and interact with the Excel UI while code is running.
- Unless you mean to *activate* a specific sheet, you never need to call `ws.Activate` in order to do 99% of what you want to do with a worksheet. Just use your `ws` variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

Third solution:
I would set `ws` to a sheet of workbook `wb` as the use of `Sheet("name")` always refers to the active workbook, which might change as your code develops.

```
sub kl() 

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    'be aware as this might produce an error, if Shet "name" does not exist
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("name")
    ' if wb is other than the active workbook
    wb.activate
    ws.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just coming across the same problem.

What you need to do is to declare `ws` as `Object`

Also it should be:

```
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

And should not be:

```
Set ws = Sheet("Sheet1")
```

The code below are working to me.

```
sub kl()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Object

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

MsgBox ws.Name

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the variable as sometimes it clashes with other modules/subs

```
 Dim Workbk As Workbook
 Dim Worksh As Worksheet
```

But also, try

```
 Set ws = wb.Sheets("name")
```

I can't remember if it works with `Sheet`

Comment: Hi, I already tried this (se comment above) but this doesn't work either. Could it have something to do with my settings?

Answer (score 0):

to your surprise, you do need to declare variable for workbook and worksheet in excel 2007 or later version. Just add single line expression.

```
Sub kl()

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("name")
    ws.select
End Sub
```

Remove everything else and enjoy.
But why to select a sheet? selection of sheets is now old fashioned for calculation and manipulation.
Just add formula like this

```
Sub kl()

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("name")
    ws.range("cell reference").formula = "your formula"
'OR in case you are using copy paste formula, just use 'insert or formula method instead of ActiveSheet.paste e.g.:
   ws.range("your cell").formula
'or
   ws.colums("your col: one col e.g. "A:A").insert
'if you need to clear the previous value, just add the following above insert line
   ws.columns("your column").delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I used `Worksheet` instead of `Worksheets` and it was resolved. Not sure what the difference is between them.

Comment: `Worksheet` is a *type* - a class name. `Worksheets` is a property of the hidden `_Globals` module, that's implicitly referring to the `Worksheets` collection of the active workbook.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim ws as Object

Set ws = Worksheets("name")
```

when declaring the worksheet as worksheet instead of an ojbect I had issues working with OptionButtons (Active X) in this worksheet (I guess the same will be with any Active-X element. When declared as object everything works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Lots of answers above! here is my take:

```
Sub kl()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("name")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

With ws
    .Select
End With

End Sub
```

your first (perhaps accidental) mistake as we have all mentioned is "Sheet"... should be "Sheets"

The with block is useful because if you set wb to anything other than the current workbook, it will ececute properly