# Excel not properly activating cell after being selected by code in a form

Tags: excel, userform, vba

The issue occurs when a cell is selected based on a UserForm which is called by a macro which is assigned to a Form control (Button) on a worksheet.

After the worksheet and cell are selected, data is not entered in the selected cells (initially) and disappears when a different cell is selected (Tab, Return, arrows keys), mouse clicking in a different cell stops the effect.

To reproduce the issue you'll need:

- A workbook with 2 sheets (Mine are named: Book1, Sheet1 and Sheet2 respectively)
- A Form control button on Sheet1
- A user form with a command button (UserForm1 and CommandButton1)
- A Module (Module1)

Module1 should contain the following:

```
Sub ShowForm()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

UserForm1 Should contain the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
        .Activate
        .Cells(5, 5).Select
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Assign the ShowForm macro to the Form control button on sheet1.

The following should happen when the button on sheet1 is clicked. The form with the button will show. If the button on the form is clicked, Sheet2 is activated and cell E5 is selected and the form is unloaded.

If at this point you try to type in sheet2 cell E5, which seems to be selected, you might notice that the text appears in the cell which was last selected on sheet1 and disappears when another cell is selected by using Tab, Enter, Arrow keys (again mouse clicking to select another cell while the cursor is in the previous cell stops the effect). Also if you then select a different cell on Sheet2 the text disappears when a different cell is selected. This effect will last until a different sheet is manually selected. You'll notice that the data you've entered on sheet2 is actually in sheet1.

If you run the ShowForm macro from the macro list which you can find under the macros button on the developer tab on the ribbon, the problem described above doesn't occur.

Also, if you place an ActiveX CommandButton on Sheet1 and add the code below to the button, there is no issue either.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    call ShowForm
End Sub
```

Why does the code work for the ActiveX control, but not the Form control?

I use Excel 2013 32bit on Windows 8.1 64bit. 
I've upgraded to Excel 2016 and the issue is persistant.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem; the code behaves as expected, but I'm using Excel 2010. Are there any special property characteristics to your worksheet and is Worksheet(2) definitely "Sheet2"?

Comment: No I've just created a new blank workbook, and then simply added a sheet with the + button on the bottom. I've discovered that when you have typed in a cell on sheet2 and while the cursor is still blinking in that cell, mouse click on a different cell, the effect stops. If you hit tab, return or arrow keys after typing in a cell, the data disappears, provided you didn't stop the effect. Mouse clicking on a different cell while there is no text being entered doesn't stop the effect.

Comment: Kudos for a clear problem description, but I also can't reproduce (using Excel 2010). Do you have any add-ins enabled? What you describe strikes me as the sort of thing that sometimes happens when event-handlers fire when you don't want them to.

Comment: @JohnColeman, I just have the solver add-in enable but nothing else. I ran into this problem when I was trying to figure out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331355/vba-causing-typed-information-to-go-to-an-incorrect-worksheet/34343310?noredirect=1#comment56481582_34343310) problem.  Would it help if I made a screen recording and posted that?

Comment: @Ambie I've just upgraded to Excel 2016 and the issue persists.

Comment: @JohnColeman, see comment above.

Comment: @SilentRevolution, I'm sorry but I can't think what to suggest. I still can't reproduce your symptoms.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem either.  Have you tried this on a different computer - just curious?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the problem is resolved, but can you try `screenupdating=False` like that:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
        .Activate
        .Cells(5, 5).Select
    End With
    Unload Me
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. I think it works.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Select
    Unload Me
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```